# Looping stops after the first item in the list

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

```
places = []
persons = []    
unknown = []
newlist = []
filename = 'file.html' 
tree = etree.parse(filename)
input_file = open(filename, 'rU')
def extract(tree):   
     <some code>
    return places
    return persons
    return unknown

def change_class():
 extract(tree)  

 for line in input_file:        
    for x in places:
         for z in unknown:                                                                       

            if x+'</dfn>' in line:

                    newline = line.replace('"person"', '"place"')
                    newlist.append(newline)

            elif z+'</dfn>' in line:

                    newline = line.replace('"person"','"undefined"')
                    newlist.append(newline)
            else:
                newlist.append(line)

            break
         break

 for x in newlist:
    print x
```

I have an html-file of this kind with erroneous class values:

> ```
>  <html>
>   <head></head>
>   <body>
>     <p class ='person'><dfn>New-York</dfn>
>     <p class = 'place'><dfn>John Doe</dfn>
>     <p class ='person'><dfn>Paris</dfn>
>     <p class = 'place'><dfn>Jane Doe</dfn>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

My script allows me to reprint the same file, but it replaces the class value only for the first item of both lists (places and unknown):

> ```
>  <html>
>   <head></head>
>   <body>
>     <p class ='place'><dfn>New-York</dfn>
>     <p class = 'unknown'><dfn>John Doe</dfn>
>     <p class ='person'><dfn>Paris</dfn>
>     <p class = 'place'><dfn>Jane Doe</dfn>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Then it kinda stops iterating over both lists and goes directly to the else-step and adds all the rest to the newlist without replacements. Python yelds no errors, list are successfully extracted with the extract() function as well, I checked...

Comment: Why don't you use regular expressions?

Comment: well you're breaking out of both inner loops without any conditions. So why would you expect more than one loop?

Comment: Where exactly should I use them?

Comment: Don't use them at all

Comment: Without both breaks it goes to infinite looping

Comment: Your `extract` function has 3 return statements. How's that ?

Comment: why not? it return 3 different lists and it works

Comment: @elaine_blath I seriously doubt that your `extract` function ever executes more than one (i.e. the first one) of those `return` statements. That's just not how Python (or most other programming languages) works...

Comment: The return of that function isn't captured either. i'm guessing the lists are treated as global since they get defined outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
known_places = #list of known places
unkowns = #list of unknown places and persons

newlist = []
for line in input_file:
    if any(place in line for place in Known_places):
        line = line.replace("person", "place")
    elif any(unkown in line for unkown in unkowns):
        line = line.replace("person","undefined")
    newlist.append(line)
```

Something like this might work.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my other answer since it was trying to solve a problem you didn't have. I see you've already accepted an answer, but do take a look at the BeautifulSoup solution as well.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PLACES = ["New-York","Paris"] # etc
PEOPLE = ["John Doe","Jane Doe"] # etc

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('file.txt'))
paragraphs = soup("p") # grabs all the <p>...</p> elements
for p in paragraphs:
    if p.dfn.string in PLACES:
        p['class'] = 'place'
    elif p.dfn.string in PEOPLE:
        p['class'] = 'person'
```

`str(soup)` is now your HTML document, modified as requested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Looks interesting, I have never used BeautifulSoup before...

Comment: @elaine_blath BeautifulSoup is an amazing parser for XML/HTML. I'm still learning it myself, but the applications are incredible! :)